# Research project scholarship in Australian university

Tags: graduate-admissions, australia

After a zoom interview and sending my cv, certificates and research proposal, one Professor has sent an email inviting me to apply for the University of Queensland PhD program admission and research scholarship of one of his projects. Can anyone enlighten me about the process of research project scholarship application? I know about Australia awards scholarship and university scholarship application but unaware about the research project scholarship application.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an industry sponsored scholarship or from the Australian Research Council (ARC), then the supervisor has full control of who he/she awards the scholarship to.  It is not as competitive as a scholarship offered by the university itself.

The application process may be the same for all scholarship applications to ensure the university captures your information.  However, instead of your application going into a pool to be ranked later, it goes directly to your supervisor who will then request the research office to issue you with an offer and the scholarship.

That's roughly how my university processes such applications.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.